# Django ORM save multiple forms at once

Tags: python, django, forms, orm

I have a question about saving three forms at once. First two forms save OK with no problems, but third form must request id from form2 when form2 is saved to database. Don't know where is problem on this procedure and where I make mistake.

## models.py

```
class Product_service(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    selling_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=5, max_digits=255, blank=True, null=True)
    purchase_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=5, max_digits=255, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="/", blank=True, null=True)
    product_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    product_code_supplier = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    product_code_buyer = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    min_unit_state = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    vat_id = models.ForeignKey('VatRate', related_name='vat_rate')
    unit_id = models.ForeignKey('Units', related_name='unit_value')
    category_id = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='product_services', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This model represent form2.

```
class InvoiceProdService(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    invoice_id = models.ForeignKey('OutgoingInvoice', related_name='outgoing_invoice', blank=True, null=True)
    prod_serv_id = models.ForeignKey('Product_service', related_name='product_services', blank=True, null=True)
    code      = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    prod_serv_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True, null=True)
    rate_name   = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True, null=True)
    units = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=5, max_digits=255, blank=True, null=True)
    vat   = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=5, max_digits=255, blank=True, null=True)
    current_vat = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=5, max_digits=255, blank=True, null=True)
    price_no_vat = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=5, max_digits=255, blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

This model represent form3. 
Where two fields are in relationship with ForeignKey to form2.

1. `invoice_id = models.ForeignKey('OutgoingInvoice', related_name='outgoing_invoice', blank=True, null=True)`
2. `prod_serv_id = models.ForeignKey('Product_service', related_name='product_services', blank=True, null=True)`

When I try with admin interface i can save form directly to database. And it works pretty well.

## views.py

Here is logic in save method:

```
if request.method == 'POST':

        form1 = InsertNewCustomer(request.POST, prefix='form1')
        form2 = Outdrew(request.POST, prefix='form2')
        form5 = MultiplyInsertValues(request.POST, prefix='form5')

        if (form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid() and form5.is_valid()):

            a, created = OrganizationInfo.objects.get_or_create(**form1.cleaned_data)

            if created:
                b = form2.save(commit=False)
                b.user_id = user_pk
                b.organization_id = org_id.id
                b.customer_id = a
                b.save()
                c = form5.save(commit=False)
                nesto = Product_service.objects.get(name= form5.cleaned_data['prod_serv_name'])
                c.prod_serv = nesto.id
                c.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/izlazni_racuni/')
            else:
                b = form2.save(commit=False)
                organ_id = OrganizationInfo.objects.get(oib=form1.cleaned_data['oib'])
                b.user_id = user_pk
                b.organization_id = org_id.id
                b.customer_id = organ_id.id
                b.save()
                c = form5.save(commit=False)
                nesto = Product_service.objects.get(name= form5.cleaned_data['prod_serv_name'])
                c.invoice_id = b.id
                c.prod_serv_id = nesto.id
                c.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/izlazni_racuni/')
        else:
            form1 = InsertNewCustomer(prefix='form1')
            form2 = Outdrew(prefix='form2')
            form5 = MultiplyInsertValues(prefix='form5')
```

After this I get error message:
Cannot assign "80": "InvoiceProdService.invoice_id" must be a "OutgoingInvoice" instance.

And problem is on line :   `c.invoice_id = b.id`

Django version : 1.7.7

Don't know where is problem on this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It comes from the way you define your fields.

```
invoice_id = models.ForeignKey('OutgoingInvoice', related_name='outgoing_invoice', blank=True, null=True)
```

The `ForeignKey` in Django adds some magic so you can work on objects directly. That is, with your definition, `invoice_id` is assumed to be an actual instance of `OutgoingInvoice`, while the numeric id will actually be *invoice_id_id*.

You probably should change `invoice_id` to `invoice` in your model:

```
invoice = models.ForeignKey('OutgoingInvoice', related_name='outgoing_invoice', blank=True, null=True)
```

If you do this, Django automagically appends `_id` to the actual database field, and you may access it either through the id, or through the objects:

```
c.invoice = b         # assign object
c.invoice_id = b.id   # or assign id
```

Actually those two lines are almost equivalent in Django.
You may find more in the documentation for [relation fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#module-django.db.models.fields.related).